# In what order to list potential future advisors?

Tags: ethics

In the department form I have to turn in each academic quarter (before I find a thesis advisor), there is a question:

> Which faculty members do you consider to be your thesis advisor (in the future)?

Suppose my answer includes four different professors, what’s the right order to list them? Should I list them alphabetically by last name, list them by academic rank, or something else?

Comment: Order of preference, perhaps?

Comment: I second @BillBarth - order of preference. You could even write that in your answer "In order of preference: A, D, B, and C"

Comment: First the ones from Gryffindor; then Hufflepuff; then Ravenclaw. And you don't want to mention the ones from Slytherin.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you please turn this comment into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Comment: @Jeromy Anglim, thanks for editing the title. That wasn't what exactly I was trying to ask. I was trying to ask without context is there any general rule when I have to list several faculties in order. However I picked a bad example where there is a clear-cut answer.

Comment: @Don Romik I know these are from Harry Potter but I don't think I get any inherit message(if any) you want to convey.

Comment: @fmlin If you feel your question would be answered more precisely if you ask it differently, I encourage you to do so! (in a separate post, obviously)
That's what we're here for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Bill Barth, @Jon Custer and @jakebeal said "Order of Preference" (subjective, of course), and requested their comments be written as an answer so that it could be upvoted. I'm happy to oblige!